# Disable automatically login for Drupal users when registering

Tags: drupal, authentication

Standard behaviour for Drupal is that the user is being logged in after he clicks his activation link and his account is activated. Since I am using a SSO solution I need to revalidate login on CAS server, so I want to disable automatically logging in after account activation.

Does anybody know how to prevent logging in / a hook for this?

Regards,

Patrick

Comment: how does clicking the activation link activates the account? do you use any module for the same?

Comment: Yes, I am using the email registration modules and that one invokes the; 

user_login_finalize()

Cant hook in to that, so I copied the module as a custom one and disabled it....

Answer (score 0):

I think https://drupal.org/project/user_verify module could be helpful for you in this scenario.